# single facebook like button for multiple items

Tags: facebook-like

I have an online e-commerce shop. What I want to do is that, when a user checks out with multiple products in its cart, he will be shown a facebook like button. If he clicks on this button, all the products selected should get liked by his facebook profile. i.e. single button -> multiple likes

Please advise how to do this.

P.S.

I am using Drupal 6 with Ubercart. Each product item has its own page and thus unique URL.

Comment: Could you share your thoughts so far please?

Comment: I haven't done this myself, but I think you can use a [batch request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) to send a number of [built-in likes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/). Good luck.

Comment: @Dipak - technically, you can try what cpilko suggested. However, you should try and make sure your app isn't spammy - which would be hard to achieve if you publish several likes with each check-out. The way you communicate to the users that X like actions will be published is also important.